# map and filter array but add modification each N elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

**SCENARIO:**

I have an observable array of objects that needs to be filtered and formatted.

I had this approach

```
messageModel.solution(self.selectedNumbers()
                          .filter(greaterThanZero)
                          .map(formatNumberSelected)
                          .join(', ');
```

With this couple of functions:

```
function greaterThanZero(number) { return number.amount() > 0 };
function formatNumberSelected(number){ return number.theNumber + " [" + number.amount() + "]" };
```

This is giving excelent results in form of a string,

```
12346 [3], 12347 [3], 12348 [3], 12349 [3], 12350 [2], 12351 [3], 12352 [3], 12353 [6], 12354 [2], 12355 [3], 12356 [2], 12357 [3], 12358 [3], 12359 [6], 12360 [3], 12361 [3], 12362 [6], 12363 [3], 12364 [6], 12365 [3], 12366 [3], 12367 [6], 12368 [3], 12369 [2], 12370 [3], 12371 [2], 12372 [6], 12373 [3], 12374 [6], 12375 [2], 12376 [3], 12377 [2], 12378 [3], 12379 [2], 12380 [6],    12381 [2], 12382 [3], 12383 [2], 12384 [6]
```

But as long as this is forming an HTML for a modal, is not very readable.

---

**EXPECTED RESULT: (simulated new line for understanding and readability!!)**

```
12346 [3], 12347 [3], 12348 [3], 12349 [3], 12350 [2]<br>, 
12351 [3], 12352 [3], 12353 [6], 12354 [2], 12355 [3]<br>, 
12356 [2], 12357 [3], 12358 [3], 12359 [6], 12360 [3]<br>, 
12361 [3], 12362 [6], 12363 [3], 12364 [6], 12365 [3]<br>, 
12366 [3], 12367 [6], 12368 [3], 12369 [2], 12370 [3]<br>, 
12371 [2], 12372 [6], 12373 [3], 12374 [6], 12375 [2]<br>, 
12376 [3], 12377 [2], 12378 [3], 12379 [2], 12380 [6]<br>, 
12381 [2], 12382 [3], 12383 [2], 12384 [6]
```

---

**ACTUAL APPROACH:**

Of course I've achieved this result with:

```
var candidates = self.selectedNumbers().filter(greaterThanZero);
var SEPARATOR = "";
var toReturn = "";
for (var item in candidates) {
  var number = candidates[item];
  toReturn = toReturn + SEPARATOR + number.theNumber + " [" + number.amount() + "]";
  if (item % 5 === 0) toReturn = toReturn + "</br>";
  SEPARATOR = ", ";
}
```

But not exactly what I'm looking for... so.. here is my

---

**QUESTION:**

So... there is a way to insert a `</br>` each N elements? In my case, would be around 5 combining `Array.prototype` built in functions?

Comment: Maybe you should just put everything in a `<li>` and use CSS to control the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array#map` passes in an optional index parameter so you could just use that:

```
function formatNumberSelected(number, i){ 
    return number.theNumber + 
           " [" + number.amount() + "]" +
           (i % 5 === 4 ? '<br>' : '');
}
```

Or separate it out into two `.map()`s so that a single function isn't doing too much:

```
messageModel.solution(self.selectedNumbers()
                      .filter(greaterThanZero)
                      .map(formatNumberSelected)
                      .map(insertBreak)
                      .join(', ');

function insertBreak(val, i) {
    return val + (i % 5 === 4 ? '<br>' : '');
}
```

Or if you have access to a library like lodash, you could chunk the numbers and then add the separators and `<br>`s (for the sake of brevity, the example below uses simple numbers instead of the types you have, but it will work on your types by using your original `greaterThanZero` and `formatNumberSelected`):

```js
var formatted = _.chain(selectedNumbers())
                 .filter(greaterThanZero)
                 .map(formatNumberSelected)
                 .chunk(5)
                 .map(addSeparators)
                 .join(', <br>');

console.log(formatted);

function greaterThanZero(number) { return number > 0 }
function formatNumberSelected(number){ 
    return "[" + number + "]"; 
}
function addSeparators(rowValues) {
    return rowValues.join(', ');
}

function selectedNumbers() {
    return [5, 6, 7, 0, 9, 3, 2, 6, 7, 0, 1, 9, 2, 9];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```